# how to use collection in drools guvnor?

Tags: collections, drools, guvnor

I would like to know how to use a collection in LHS of a rule (to be used in contains, memberof) , which can be managed in Guvnor containing big list of elements (may be tens of thousands). Take a blacklist match for an example, how can i maintain the big blacklist in guvnor very efficiently ? 
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Models are something like this:

```
declare MyItem
end
```

and

```
declare MyList extends ArrayList 
end
```

You need to use the formula for the field. Click the list, then New Formula and write

```
this contains myItem
```

Or when using memberOf. Again use formula now for the MyItem

```
this memberOf myList
```

You could just insert each blacklist item into the working memory. This is more efficient than using memberOf or contains. It also makes it easier to write rules using Guvnor. If the List contains strings you can do this:

```
declared ListItem 
  name:String 
end
```

You can use Drools to insert the rules from the list (you can also do this before firing the rules in Java code):

```
rule "Just to empty the list" 
 when 
   list:List() 
 then 
   for(String name:list) 
     insert(Item(name)); 
end
```

Now you can write the rules against the black list items.

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder whether it will work efficiently if I use List in a rule. The blacklist is stored in database, when a fact is inserted into work-memory, I'd like to check if a field(say ID) of this fact is in blacklist. Is there a way to make the blacklist object maintained in work-memory all the time? So that each rule match is effient. Can 'global' do this? I am new to drools, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend testing this before you start optimising your application design. It could be a complete non-issue!

However, if you have a huge blacklist, then inserting it into the working memory might be the slow step. The fact insertion will lead to it being propagated through the Rete network, and depending on how many rules depend on its contents, this could be a slow process. Once the Rete network has been updated, subsequent evaluations should be quick.

Therefore, depending on how your rules/sessions operate, one technique to optimise performance could be to create a long-running session and insert the blacklist on start-up. With this, you could insert a 'request' fact and see what fires, then retract the request, so working memory is ready for the next request.

Unfortunately, this does raise a few other issues. For instance, depending on your rules, you may need to synchronize access to the session, rather than sharing it. This leads to a situation where responses are fast, but must also wait for one another to finish, which could be a scalability issue. If that were to be a problem, you could create a pool of sessions to support simultaneous querying by multiple users.